Implementing darkTheme Configuration in Custom Flutter App Structure
I'm working on a Flutter project with a custom app structure that doesn't use the typical MaterialApp widget for configuration. Instead, we manage app configurations through a custom AppConfig class. Now, I'm aiming to integrate a toggle button to switch between light and dark themes, similar to how it's traditionally implemented within MaterialApp. How can I achieve this toggle functionality within our custom app structure?
Here's a breakdown of my project structure:

AppConfig Class:
I have an AppConfig class defined in config/app_config.dart to manage app configurations. Currently, it includes properties like appName and other custom configurations.
class AppConfig {
  final String appName;

  AppConfig({
    required this.appName,
  });
}


Main Entry Point:
My main entry point (main.dart) initializes the app based on configurations provided by AppConfig.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'config/app_config.dart';
import 'config/app_init.dart';
import 'restart_widget.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  AppConfig devAppConfig = AppConfig(
    appName: 'MedCare',
  );
  Widget app = await initializeApp(devAppConfig);
  runApp(RestartWidget(child: app));
}


Desired Implementation of darkTheme:
I want to extend the AppConfig class to include a darkTheme property and apply this theme configuration globally within my app. Ideally, I'd like to implement this darkTheme configuration in a way that mirrors how it's typically done within MaterialApp:
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.light(),
  darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
  themeMode: ThemeMode.system, // or ThemeMode.light/dark
  home: MyHomePage(),
);


Integration Challenges:
How can I modify my custom app initialization process to accommodate the darkTheme configuration similar to the traditional approach used within MaterialApp? Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on how to set up and apply the darkTheme globally within my app structure without relying on MaterialApp directly.


I've attempted to extend the AppConfig class to include a darkTheme property similar to the ThemeData.dark() approach used in MaterialApp. However, I'm unsure how to integrate this darkTheme configuration effectively within my custom app initialization process (main.dart structure).
I would greatly appreciate any advice, code examples, or best practices on how to implement and apply the darkTheme configuration in a custom Flutter app structure without using MaterialApp directly.

Consider using a ThemeExtension. Keeps things simple.
extension CoreThemeExtensions on BuildContext {
  TextStyle? get largeText => Theme.of(this).textTheme.displayLarge;
}

Then just apply the theme to your control.
For example:
Text("MySampleText", style: context.largeText)

The Light/Dark mode will be dependent on the themeMode attribute value you set to your MaterialApp class.
You can also add a listener, to listen to toggle states when changing between Light/Dark modes.
class AppThemeListener with ChangeNotifier {
  static bool darkMode = false;

  ThemeMode currentTheme() {
    return darkMode ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
  }

  void toggleTheme() {
    darkMode = !darkMode;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

Then in your Flutter app's Application Component (where you specify your MaterialApp, register the listener
class SystemAppTheme {
  static final systemThemeNotifier = AppThemeListener();
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
    
  SystemAppTheme.systemThemeNotifier.addListener(() {
    setState(() {});
  });
}

To then switch theme on your app invoke this (you can invoke this anywhere in your app, and it will automatically redraw the app, pass the theme to use into your component's build context, and thus you can switch between Light & DarkMode):
AppThemeListener.systemThemeNotifier.toggleTheme();

